# How to make a camera auto focus for an object in React-Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to make a camera can focus for an object in real-time. 
I want the camera focus on the label of a medicine bottle.
I've attched an Image to clearify what I want.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3p8U.png)

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?